# How to get the query displayed when a change is made to a table or a field in a table in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have used mysql for some projects and recently I moved to postgresql. In mysql when I alter a table or a field the corresponding query will be displayed in the page. But such a feature was not found in postgresql(kindly excuse me if I'm wrong). Since the query was readily available it was very helpful for me to test something in the local database(without explicitly typing the query), copy the printed query and run it in the server. Now it seems like I've to manually do all the trick. Even though I'm familiar with the query operations,at times it can be pretty time consuming process. Can anybody help me? How can I get the corresponding query to get displayed in postgresql(like in mysql) whenever a change is made to the table?

Comment: What IDE you use to work with postgresql?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The corresponding query to what? When you alter a table you already *have* a query (because you run a `ALTER TABLE` statement. So what do you mean with "is displayed"? Seems more like a client/IDE/SQL tool thing.

Comment: Btw: Your whole way of managing your schema migration is not good in the first place. You shouldn't be doing ad-hoc changes where you rely on some strange tool to display you what you already did just to be able to copy and paste it. Plan the changes, put them into a SQL script, store the script in a version control system (svn, git) and apply this in a controlled manner into production.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `SELECT * FROM ...` there should not be any reason for your output to not include newly added columns, no matter how you get your results - would that be `psql` in command line, PgAdmin3 or any other IDE.

After you add new columns, it is possible that these changes are still in open transaction in other window or SQL command - be sure to COMMIT such transaction. Note that your changes to data or schema will not be visible to any other database clients until transaction commits.

If your IDE still does not show changes, maybe you need to refresh list of tables or if that option is not available, restart your IDE. If that does not work still, maybe you should use better IDE.

If you have used `SELECT field1, field2, ... FROM ...` then you must add new fields into your SELECT statement(s) - but this would be true for any other SQL implementation, MySQL included.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [LISTEN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-listen.html) / [NOTIFY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-notify.html) mechanism in PostgreSQL to notify your client on altering the database schema.